# Calculate parasite drag coefficient from drag polar

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance

The drag polar of an electric-powered unmanned aircraft is

$$ C_D = 0.038 + 0.0458 C_L^2 $$

What is the parasite drag coefficient?

Answer (score 3):

Well, $C_D = C_{D,0} + k_1 C_L^2 + k_2 C_L$ according to Brandt et al's "Introduction to Aeronautics: A Design Perspective," so the parasite drag coefficient is $C_{D,0}$ or 0.038.

(Also, $k_1 = 0.0458$ and $k_2 = 0$.)